# I want to detect changes on @input Object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to detect changes on 'draft' Object from the parent component but ngOnChange() doesn't fire.
this is my try but it is not even enter the debugger

```
  @Input() draft: Contribution;
```

```
 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
 debugger
    if (changes.draft && changes.draft.currentValue) {
      this.loadDraft();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Change detection only fires for inputs if the reference changes. If your input is an object, a property change on that object will not trigger OnChanges

Answer (score 0):

You could detect all the changes for `draft` in the child component where `draft` is declared, and then you could emit an `EventEmitter` to the parent notifying that like the following:

**child component**

```js
@Component({
  ...,
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() draft!: Contribution;
  @Output() change = new EventEmitter<Contribution>();

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    console.log('draft changed: ', this.draft);
    this.change.emit(this.draft);
  }
}
```

**parent component**

```js
@Component({
  ...
  template: '<app-child [draft]="data" (change)="onChildChange($event)"></app-child>'
})
export class ParentComponent {
  data: Contribution = {...};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // for triggering the ngOnChanges from the child
    setTimeout(() => this.data = {...anotherObject }, 2500)
  }

  onChildChange(event: Contribution): void {
    console.log('data changed...', event);
  }
}
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ll74we?file=src%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Findex.html)